# Quarkus app to reverse proxy another old CGI web app

Tags: reverse-proxy, quarkus

Does Quarkus provide a Guide to reverse proxy a old CGI web app?
I have 3 requirements

1. Put OIDC in front of the old web app
2. When a session starts, fill in the returned "log in" page, submit that log in page, and return the log in response
3. When required, Inspect a response from the old web app for data to use outside of the old web app.

I have requirement 1 completed with a simple servlet.  requirements 2 and 3 are works in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this proxy servlet](https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet)

It works in Quarkus

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy</groupId>
    <artifactId>smiley-http-proxy-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the details of how you made it work for a quarkus project? I am quite new to the whole java and quarkus world so am struggling to figure this out but still no success.

Answer (score 1):

We currently do have any such guides on the website.